# Config section is empty and non-empty

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this:

```
  defmodule SomeModule do
    @my_custom_config_section (Application.get_env(:my_app, :common)[:key1][:key2])

    IO.puts("@my_custom_config_section debug1: #{Kernel.inspect(@my_custom_config_section)}")
    IO.puts("@my_custom_config_section debug2: #{@my_custom_config_section}")


    # ..........
```

And I have this when trying to run it - during compilation:

```
    @my_custom_config_section (Application.get_env(:my_app, :common)[:key1][:key2])

    # goood! the values are correct!

    @my_custom_config_section debug1: %{aaa: "", bbb: "fdsafds", ccc: false, dddd: "afdsafdsfdsfds"}


    # also good!
  == Compilation error in file lib/my_app/some_module.ex ==
  ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for  %{aaa: "", bbb: "fdsafds", ccc: false, dddd: "afdsafdsfdsfds"}
```

However! This prints an empty string

```
  defmodule SomeModule do
    @my_custom_config_section (Application.get_env(:my_app, :common)[:key1][:key2])

    #IO.puts("@my_custom_config_section debug1: #{Kernel.inspect(@my_custom_config_section)}")
    #IO.puts("@my_custom_config_section debug2: #{@my_custom_config_section}")


    # <--------- emtpy!
    # @my_custom_config_section debug3: 
    IO.puts("@my_custom_config_section debug3: #{Kernel.inspect(@my_custom_config_section)}")
```

And this founds nothing in @my_custom_config_section:

```
    def my_action(conn, params) do
      a1 = @my_custom_config_section

      # a1 is empty! Why???


    end
```

At compile time, data exists. At runtime - not anymore.

Comment: Are you sure you included `:key3` in your configuration? It may help to see the entire final example code and it's output. Also, you can use `IO.inspect(@my_custom_config_section, label: "@my_custom_config_section debug2")`. This would avoid your needing to call inspect inside your puts.

Comment: Could you please remove all successful calls (we know that `Application.get_env/2` works.) Also, please specify exactly what you are doing, what you have received and what you had expected to receive.